# Accessing BIOS taking literal hours in laptop

Tags: windows-10, bios, asus-laptop, laptop-repair

*Apologies if this is the wrong sub*

I'm troubleshooting a weird issue on a friends laptop and I'm a bit taken aback as to why it's doing this. Essentially it's an asus E403S laptop and when you power it up, there is a splash screen and nothing else. After I left it on for a few hours it eventually gave me a windows error but never left the splash screen. I tried accessing the bios with no success so I opened it up removed the battery, reset the bios and visually inspected the components before putting it back together. Nothing out of the ordinary, just no actual hard drive cause it's EMMC. I plugged a recovery key and booted it back up and pressed every single asus combination to boot into the bios and then left it alone, 2 hours later I was in. So I moved to deactivate the windows hdd in case it was the problem and every press locked the bios for about 30 minutes. After another 2 hours, I finally managed to boot into the recovery key and as I'm writing this it has been 4 hours and the windows esd recovery key is at 50%.

I have my suspicious that the hdd is not the culprit but something is failing, might anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: It unfortunately wasn't my choice (I'm attempting a repair for a friend) and it's an integrated EMMC flash drive so it's part of the motherboard as specified above. Also, most laptops don't come with a hardware repair manual because the proprietary nature of the internals.  I was simply asking if someone might have a better idea than I do as to why this is happening to better understand the problem at hand

Comment: This is why I tell folks to buy ThinkPads because they DO have a HW manual.